GAMLSS - How to adjust AIC for log-transformation of variables
I have one GAMLSS model in which the independent and dependent variable are on the natural scale, and a second model in which both variables have been log-transformed. How do I adjust the AIC of the log-transformed one so that the two models can be compared?
(This may not be important for answering the question, but in case you wonder, I am modelling the CV of measurements as a function of their true value. I have a few thousand unknown true values, and two measurements of each of them.
In the natural scale model, I use the mean of two measurements (as an estimator of the true value) as the independent variable, and the sample SD's as the dependent variable. The resulting mu of the GAMLSS model is an estimate of the dependent population SD, which can then be used to calculate the dependent population CV.
I then make a model with the means of the log-transformed measurements as the dependent variable and their SD's as the dependent variable, which estimates the dependent population CV directly.)
Here is an example:
library(matrixStats)
library(gamlss)

set.seed(0)

# Simulate data
x_mu <- rGB2(5000, 2.7, 8.6, 0.13, 1.28)
x_mu <- x_mu[x_mu > .5]

cv <- function(x) .03 * exp(-1 * x) + .01

# Pretend you didn't know that the data was generated by rlnorm()
dat <- as.data.frame(matrix(
  rlnorm(2 * length(x_mu), log(x_mu), cv(x_mu)),
  ncol = 2
))

# Assuming that the errors are normally distributed
dat_normal <- dat
dat_normal$mean <- rowMeans(dat_normal)
dat_normal$sd <- rowSds(as.matrix(dat_normal[, 1:2]))

model_normal <- gamlss(sd ~ pbm(mean, mono = "up"),
                     ~ mean,
                     data = dat_normal,
                     family = GG(),
                     control = gamlss.control(n.cyc = 50))

# Assuming that the errors are log-normally distributed
dat_lognormal <- log(dat)
dat_lognormal$logmean <- rowMeans(dat_lognormal)
dat_lognormal$logsd <- rowSds(as.matrix(dat_lognormal[, 1:2]))

model_lognormal <- gamlss(logsd ~ pbm(logmean, mono = "down"),
                        ~ logmean,
                        data = dat_lognormal,
                        family = GG(),
                        control = gamlss.control(n.cyc = 50))

x_compare <- c(.5, 1, 2, 4)
compare <- data.frame(
  x = x_compare,
  true = cv(x_compare),
  model_normal = exp(predict(model_normal, newdata = data.frame(mean = x_compare))) / x_compare,
  model_lognormal = exp(predict(model_lognormal, newdata = data.frame(logmean = log(x_compare))))
)

round(compare, 4)
x     true    model_normal  model_lognormal
0.5   0.0282  0.0303        0.0295
1.0   0.0210  0.0215        0.0215
2.0   0.0141  0.0146        0.0146
4.0   0.0105  0.0112        0.0099

AIC(model_normal, model_lognormal)

                df       AIC
model_lognormal 6.141213 -28058.55
model_normal    8.663739 -24779.60
```


Good question, +1, but I'm very much afraid the answer is "you can't, at least not in general". I would love to be proven wrong.

I'm with @StephanKolassa on this; the response data is different between the two so the likelihoods are different and I'm not aware of a way to fix that. But... why don't you use family = LOGNO() for the log-normal directly? That way you could compare the AICs because you'd use the same, untransformed response variable in both models. Unless I've missed something obvious, that is...

I think are a few similar questions on Cross Validated, and some of them have been answered. IIRC, there is an adjustment factor via the Jacobian of the transformation... Perhaps these threads could be helpful? Maybe this? @StephanKolassa

@GavinSimpson Even though the measurement errors are log-normally distributed, the distribution of sample SD's is not. As it turns out, the generalised gamma family gives the lowest AIC when using the chooseDist() function, both on the natural and log-scale.

@RichardHardy It is tempting to simply add sum(2*log(dat_lognormal$logsd)) to the AIC of the log-transformed model, but is that approach valid for GAMLSS models? Or does it pertain specifically to linear models? My understanding of this subject is limited, thus my question.

@PederHolman, I have not dug into this myself, so I cannot tell. Sorry.
